# How to get Android Serial or Android ID from Setting menu (or somewhere else in the UI)

Tags: java, android, device

I obtained the Android serial number by code using

```
android.os.Build.SERIAL
```

I then compare it to the serial number found in the Settings menu (Settings-> About device-> Status-> Serial number).

I've tested it, and it seems that on some devices (e.g. Nexus) the two codes are the same, while on others (e.g. Galaxy Note) the two codes are completely different: The Java code returns me a 16-digit alphanumeric (lowercase) code, while on screen I can see an 11-digit alphanumeric (uppercase) code.

- How is it possible? Are these two codes the same, or something completely different?
- If they are the same, is there a way to convert from one of the two to the other?
- Is there a better way to identify the device? I know that I can use

  1. the phone device ID (IMEI, MEID,...), which can be obtained

     ```java
     TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
     tManager.getDeviceId();
     ```

     but not all devices are phones, and not all of them have this code;
  2. The Android ID, retrievable by

     ```java
     Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(),Secure.ANDROID_ID);
     ```

     But I cannot find it anywhere in the Settings menu, and I need my user to tell me its code by reading it from the user interface.

Comment: And did you compare the completely different display to the Android ID instead of the Build.SERIAL?

Comment: Of course I did. Android ID and Android serial are two different 16-digits alphanumeric lowercase codes.

Comment: I hope you don't rely on this 16 char observation too much because I have seen different ones. ;) But anyways, I presume you need this for support requests, and the general recommendation in this regard is to generate an own installation UUID and use that, because neither Build.SERIAL nor ANDROID_ID are reliable enough. Your app could show the installation ID to the user. But of course, that's also a solution for your current calamity; if you decide to live with SERIAL's lack of reliability, that is.

Comment: I think my answer in this Question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13248481/settings-secure-android-id-always-the-same-on-each-device/13248925#13248925) helps you.

Comment: Class Stacker: I know, I've seen different kinds of serials myself ;) they seem to behave differently on each device family. Unfortunately I need to know an ID, and I need to know it before installing my app.
Bandits: thanks, I had already seen your answer googling around! ;) I was going to use the ANDROID_ID in fact, but I have to explain my user where to find it, and I haven't seen this code anywhere in the phone settings

Answer (score 0):

The app "Android id" on google play(free) shows different ID's like:

- android_ID
- android.os.build.serial
- telephonyManager deviceID
- wifi mac